# Schema to build a user updates dashboard activities ala facebook

Tags: php, mysql, schema

Assuming that I have a simple website where users can upload photos and they follow each other.
If I follow someone I can see all the updates the users I follow do. Period.

So the user dashboard will show the recent photo uploaded. Simple as that.

My question is:

I was wondering if is better to just query the photo table for where the photos have user-id of people I follow, or create an activity table where I can store the upload etc, or is this redundant?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose it depends how many different kinds of updates you want to show your users.  If photos are the only thing you want to display, it's probably not worth making a separate table.

But if you have lots of different kinds of updates then it could be worth making an "updates" table to aggregate them so you only have to query one table to display the dashboard.